# Allowing User to Select multiple items in a GridView

Tags: arrays, xml, android-arrayadapter, android-adapter

Very new to coding through Android with no knowledge of Java watsoever. I've been putting together pieces through other questions posted but I'm struggling. 
I created an array called 'images2' at the top of my OnCreate method and put a bunch of colors from my drawable into it, one by one. That part works great but I've been trying to create an onClickListner that has an OnClick method that changes the drawable when you click on it to another color. I want them all to change to the same color. I know that I can set the selector programmatically: gridview2.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK)); but change the selector, either in the backend or XMl code doesn't help me get the new drawable to stick. So I created another listArray in the adapter and I can call it in the main. I have an index in the onClick that will go through all 25 possible item positions and I want to make it so that it will change the drawable to each position that is in the array. It also adds the current position clicked into the array myarray.add(position); but I just realized that value might not be being saved. The arrayList is declared public but it is declared public within the adapter so do changes in the OnCreate have no effect? I'm sorry. THAT is definitely a noobinoob-noob question.

```js
/**
 * Created by Jordan on 3/25/2017.
 */

public class Welcome extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.welcome);

        final List<Integer> images2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        images2.add(R.drawable.grid1);images2.add(R.drawable.grid6);
        images2.add(R.drawable.grid2);images2.add(R.drawable.grid2);
        images2.add(R.drawable.grid3);images2.add(R.drawable.grid1);
        images2.add(R.drawable.grid4);images2.add(R.drawable.grid3);
        images2.add(R.drawable.grid5);images2.add(R.drawable.grid2);
        images2.add(R.drawable.grid6);images2.add(R.drawable.grid6);
        images2.add(R.drawable.open);images2.add(R.drawable.grid4);
        images2.add(R.drawable.grid1);images2.add(R.drawable.grid1);
        images2.add(R.drawable.grid6);images2.add(R.drawable.grid4);
        images2.add(R.drawable.grid4);images2.add(R.drawable.grid2);
        images2.add(R.drawable.grid3);images2.add(R.drawable.grid3);
        images2.add(R.drawable.grid6);images2.add(R.drawable.grid1);
        images2.add(R.drawable.grid5);

        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        final GridView gridview2 = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.welcomeGrid);

        final Welcome.ImageAdapter mAdapter = new Welcome.ImageAdapter(this, images2);
        gridview2.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        gridview2.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        gridview2.setItemChecked(2, true);
        gridview2.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        gridview2.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
               // ArrayList<Integer> clickedStatus = new ArrayList<Integer>();

                 ArrayList<Integer> clickedStatus = new ArrayList<>(25);
                clickedStatus.add(position);
                if (position == 12){
                    setContentView(R.layout.login);
                }
                else if(position != 12) {
                    // no matter, whether the item has already been clicked or not I want this toast to pop up to promp the user to actually enter the app and sign in
                    Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "You selected " + position+ ".. Please select middle tile to enter!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if(clickedStatus.contains(position)){
                        // as soon as it's noticed that the an integer matching the current position is currently stored in the
                        // array list (clickedStatus), I want it removed right below
                       // was passing item in place of position into the remove(). Don't know why Integer item = (Integer) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                        //I want to go through 25 numbers and
                        for(int i=0; i<25;i++ ){
                                // compare those ints to what is in contained in the clickedstatus
                            if(clickedStatus.contains(i)){
                              //  Drawable Marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.celeb1);
                                images2.set(i, R.drawable.celeb1);
                                //for every int that is stored in click status I want
                                // to call the item and change the background of that item to a specified drawable file.

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        clickedStatus.add(position);
                     //   images2.set(position, );
                        for(int i=1; i<25;i++ ){
                            // compare those ints to what is in contained in the clickedstatus
                            if(clickedStatus.contains(i)){
                                //  Drawable Marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.celeb1);
                                images2.set(i, R.drawable.celeb1);
                                //for every int that is stored in click status I want
                                // to call the item and change the background of that item to a specified drawable file.

                            }
                        }

                    }
                  //  gridview2.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
                   // mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
        );
    }
// I think this got generated automatically at some point somehow. Might of been with the multichoicemode line above ^
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Context mContext;
        //IMAGES ARE REFERENCED HERE V---
        private List<Integer> mImages2;
        public ArrayList<Integer> clickedStatus = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        //create array to store whether an item has been clicked or not. needs to be public!!

        //check to determine the case in the below method

        // IGNORE THIS
        // private int selectedPosition = -1;
        //public void setSelectedPosition(int position) {
        //  selectedPosition = position;
        //}

            public ImageAdapter( final Context c, final List<Integer> images2){
            mContext = c;
            mImages2 = images2;


        }

        public int getCount() {
            return mImages2.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 1;
        }
        // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
                imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(140, 120));
                imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            if(clickedStatus.contains(position)){
                convertView.setSelected(true);
                convertView.setPressed(true);
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }

            imageView.setImageResource(mImages2.get(position));
            return imageView;
        }
        ;}
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I know the code I have up there is an absolute mess but I'm kind of multi tasking trying to do several things at once. I've had like 15+ tabs to overstack open at a time and it's just easier to keep things right in front of my face. Please help though. This is my final project for my MSIS Bachelors degree and my group has basically left the whole thing, from head to toe, up to me!!

Comment: I would really like to try to leave as much in tact as possible (disclosing the things that do nothing) but If I need to overhaul things because of a strong direct answer I'm all down for that too. I'm still working on it now so don't think I'm just leaving it to the God's of overstack! I work a lot but I'll be off a couple days which will probably really help this week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created and finalized a different set of Arrays for holding every possible five combinations of selections that would result in a win. Titled Diagonal (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Horizontal(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) , Vertical (1, 2, 3, 4, 5), etc. Upon click a value is stored at the appropriate position of the ListArray and I have relative checks (if statements) that loops everytime the button is click. Does not slow the app down substantially, looks ugly on paper but is very functional without the use of checkboxes.  If anybody is interested in seeing the code they may comment.